# How to trigger Angular handlers programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form element with an ng-change handler.  I want to programmatically trigger the handler, but without direct inspection of scope.  I want to do this because I'm writing a Chrome extension so I can't easily access '$scope' to get the handler.

I have tried the obvious choice of

```
$(element).triggerHandler('change')
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  See example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/iaz7trxVT09XWBktGhE9?p=preview (in this example I'm logging some lines to console when the change handler runs, but clicking the button doesn't log those lines).

I tried a few other methods found in various threads here, such as trigger() or manual construction of event and fire with dispatchEvent but to no avail.  I don't quite understand why the event handler isn't triggering.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Unlike other `ng-<event>` directives, `ng-change` is not bound to the underlying element's `change` event. It is bound to `ng-model`'s `$viewChangeListeners`, so there is no way to invoke it manually, unless you have access to tge scope. Why are you using `ng-change`? Would `ng-input` work instead?

Comment: Thanks.  That explains a lot!  I can't control the page as I'm writing a Chrome extension to fill in forms, but this explains why my code wasn't working!

Comment: actually you can access $scope from the outside world by using `scope = angular.element($(element)).scope()`, so there is no need to trigger `change`

Comment: I don't even have access to 'angular' inside a Chrome extension.  I suppose I can load angular JS file in and see if that works (it should - I can also just extract the code that runs ```angular.element(element).scope()``` as it's pure JS and the data should be stored in DOM anyway).

Comment: @user3759055 have you found any solution????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently (according to [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)), the model change will not be triggered when the value is not changed. An ugly (yet effective) workaround would be to actually change the value briefly:

```
var v = $('#testField1').val();
$('#testField1').val(0)
$('#testField1').triggerHandler('change');
$('#testField1').val(v)
$('#testField1').triggerHandler('change');
```

Of course this will trigger the event twice, if this is a problem you could for example use a known "magic value" (e.g. min negative integer) and ignore it.

Alternatively, I'm afraid there is no simple solution: you might need to access the scope / controller to invoke the function you want directly or meddle with angular's event handling.